# Unable to access local web server on chromeOS

Tags: google-chrome, webserver, google-chrome-os

I had this chromebook running a local http weberver on port 80 at 127.0.0.0, but whenever I try to connect to it it just shows "connection refused". I think it might be the firewall, is there any way to bypass it? I tried both chrome and firefox, both returned same thing

Comment: Hi james. `127.0.0.0` or `127.0.0.1`? Also, crostini passes open ports to your system, so you should be able to enter `localhost:80` from Chrome.